# I can't send email in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

When i send email there is an exception which says "failure sending mail".

```
var mailObj = new MailMessage("marabifuad2013@gmail.com", "to Email");
mailObj.Subject = "subject";
mailObj.Body ="";
mailObj.IsBodyHtml = true;
var smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("marabifuad2013@gmail.com", "password");
smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpServer.Send(mailObj);
```

Comment: Surely there must be more information in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that because you haven't specified to use SSL:

```
smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
```

Also you can try:

```
smtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Apart from that everything looks fine, providing that you entering correct credentials and etc.